# Wi-Fi Direct services scanner application for Android

Tags: android, networking, wifi

I am searching for an application that can scan all the [Wi-Fi Direct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct) [Bonjour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29) services reachable from my Android device.

These are the kind of services that I am looking for: [Using Wi-Fi P2P for Service Discovery](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[NetX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tools.netgel.netx)** might be the tool you're looking for:

[image: NetX] [image: NetX] [image: NetX]
<sup>*NetX* (source: [Google Play](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrLKom.png); click images for larger variants)</sup>

From the app's description:

> Discovers all devices connected to the network. Displays most important information for each device connected, IP Address, MAC Address, Vendor, Bonjour Name, NetBIOS Name and Domain.

You didn't specify what exact features (besides device discovery) you might need – so that's the closest match I can give ;)